# Vba to vlookup value & copy next cell value to invoice sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Formula use for Vlookup
`activeWS.cell("A9") =INDEX(Breaking_Data!F5:F,MATCH(A8,Breaking_Data!A5:A,0))`

I try to run it in VBA code but it doesn't work, any one know how to modify it for VBA code.
that lookup A8 cell value in `ws("Breaking_Data")` with Range("A5:A").lastcellvalue if any value match then copy same row cell value form range ("F5:F") & paste it in active sheet cell A9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim lastR as Long: LastR = Worksheets("Breaking_Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

activeWS.cell("A9").Value = Application.Evaluate _
    ("Index(Breaking_Data!F5:F" & lastR & ", Match(A8, Breaking_Data!A5:A" & lastR & ", 0))")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

You can include it as a function:

```
activeWS.cell("A9") = "INDEX(Breaking_Data!F5:F1048576,MATCH(A8,Breaking_Data!A5:A1048576,0))"
```

or you can get the value itself:

```
activews.Range("A9") = Application.Index(Sheets("Breaking_Data").Range("F5:F1048576"), Application.Match(activews.Range("A8"), Sheets("Breaking_Data").Range("A5:A1048576"), 0))
```